# Service started by PhoneStateListener is killed before finished

Tags: android, service

I have a question about service behavior when started by a PhoneStateListener.

My client wants a security software to track stolen devices. The feature I'm writing take pictures when SEND button is pressed.

So I wrote a broadcastreceiver registering a PhoneStateListener. This listener starts a service to take pictures from facing camera without a preview. The problem is the timing. The service is being killed before the picture is available! But why a service is being killed by SO?

By Broadcastreceiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class PhoneReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ATMPhoneStateListener phoneListener=new ATMPhoneStateListener(context);
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
}
```

The PhoneStateListener:

```
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Binder;
import com.my.services.TakePictureService;

public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

private Context context;

public MyPhoneStateListener (Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){
    switch(state)
    {
       case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            break;
       case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
           phoneIsOffHeek(); 

            break;
       case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
           break;
    }
}   

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private void phoneIsOffHeek() {
        Intent takePictureService = new Intent(context, TakePictureService.class);
        context.startService(takePictureService);           
}
}
```

The Service:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class TakePictureService extends Service {

private Context context;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    context = this.getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    if (GBCameraUtil.findFrontFacingCamera() != -1) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmDDhhmmss");
        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        final String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + date + ".jpg";  

        GBTakePictureNoPreview c = new GBTakePictureNoPreview(context, this);
        c.setUseFrontCamera(true);
        c.setFileName(fileName);

        if (c.cameraIsOk()) {
            try {
                c.takePicture();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

    } else {
    stopSelf();
    }
}
```

The permissions are ok, the code works sometimes and sometimes don't, because the service is killed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. The service was started twice and the second starts was killing the first one.